# Python decorator for function fetching JSON request

Tags: python, request, decorator

I cannot pass the `url-details` from the decorated functions to the decorator.

While debugging, the `url-details` in the decorated functions will be ignored. How can I solve that problem using decorators to avoid duplicated code?

## Edit

There is a Webservice, that provides JSON data. I found duplicated code in the codebase: For each get request, there is a separate function (`fetch_all`, `fetch_key`, `fetch_date`, etc). Each function creates the URL (`url_base` + `url_mid` + `url_details`), defines the header and fetches the response the same way, only the url_detail is different.

Now I want to refactor that ugly, duplicated code that way: Only define `url_details` in existing functions and remove whole url-creating, header defining and finally fetching the response (by `requests.get(...)`) into a decorator.

## Decorator

```py
def fetch(fnc):
    def wrapper(access_token, url_detail="", debug=None):
        headers = {"Authorization": "xxx " + access_token, "Accept": "application/json"}
        url = f"{url_base}{url_mid}{url_detail}"
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        if debug:
            print(response)
        return response.content
    return wrapper
```

## Decorated functions

```py
@fetch
def fetch_all(access_token):
    return access_token, ""

@fetch
def fetch_key(access_token, key=None):
    return access_token, f"/{key}"

@fetch
def fetch_date(access_token, date=""):
    return access_token, f"?date={date}", True
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? I'm unclear what issue you're running into / what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've added the idea in 'Edit'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused by exactly what you are trying to achieve, but I have some idea why you might be having difficulty.

By decorating your function with `@fetch` you are passing the original function as `fnc`.

You are then defining a new function (`wrapper`) which you return as the result of the decorator. However you never call `fnc` from within your new function, this means that it will never be run!

Your decorator will always return the same `wrapper` function, regardless of the function that you are decorating.

Your current code is the equivalent of

```py
def wrapper(access_token, url_detail="", debug=None):
    headers = {"Authorization": "xxx " + access_token, "Accept": "application/json"}
    url = f"{url_base}{url_mid}{url_detail}"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    if debug:
        print(response)
    return response.content

fetch_all = wrapper
fetch_key = wrapper
fetch_date = wrapper
```

Comment: Good clarification, I'll try without decorator!

Comment: If you want to make functions which have common code but with some differences in starting conditions (in this case the URL you want). You might want to check out `partial` from the `functools` library.